# Create multiple model instances using one ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to create a form which creates and saves multiple model instances. 
The model is `Job`. What I want to do is to create a form with one extra multiplechoice field `target_languages`. If user choose multiple languages, multiple instances will be created and each of this instances will have one `target_languages`.

So if user choose `language_from = 'EN'` and `target_languages = ['RU','HU','GE']` there will be three `Job` instances created.

`<Job 'EN' to 'RU'>`, `<Job 'EN' to 'HU'>` and `<Job 'EN' to 'GE'>`

I suppose this could be done using `ModelForm` and overriding `save` method but I'm not sure how to continue.

```
class NewOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    target_languages = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Language.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ['language_from', 'target_languages', 'text_to_translate', 'notes','short_description', ]

    def save(self):
        for target_language in self.cleaned_data['target_languages']:
            self.instance.language_to = target_language
            self.instance.save()
```

The problem is that in this case, the one instance will be overriden instead of creating new instance in each iteration.

Do you know how to do that?

Comment: If you clear the primary_key, `self.instance.pk = None`, this will enforce the creation of new instances. However I feel it like a hacky solution, maybe using a `formset` will be more suitable in your situation?